# Read-only (silent) select in Vim

Tags: gvim

When I select text in Vim using the mouse, the editor displays "SELECT" at the bottom of the window, like so:

[image]

This always makes me uneasy, because I have found that the Select mode somehow changes very easily into Insert mode.  Is there a way to have a "read-only select mode", if you will, such that Vim does not react in any way in response to mouse select operations?

I am using Vim 8.0.586 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Get rid of mswin.vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093578/how-to-make-gvim-on-windows-behave-exacly-like-linux-console-vim) that comes activated by default on Windows platforms.

Instead of the select-mode, you'll be back in the visual-mode. It's not read-only strictly speaking, but at least it's not half-way between insert-mode and visual-mode.

Comment: `set selectmode-=mouse`

Comment: @Mass. Indeed. It's a consequence of `behave mswin`. All these mswin stuff are the root of many problems when we come to Vim on Windows boxes from a *nix background. IMO, it's best to get rid of it. I doubt there are that many people using vim that desire their editor to behave like notepad.

Comment: @Mass Thank you and thanks to Luc.  I didn't realize that `behave mswin` caused these problems.

Comment: Heck yeah. I have a 50-50 *nix/Win background yet the first thing I do with a new installation of Vim for Win is get rid of that nonsense. :)